# YII 2, Method Not Allowed (#405)

Tags: post, get, yii2, http-status-code-405

- When i delete a Record in GridView i got this Error on my Hosting
  Server.
- Local its working without Problems.

**What i dont understand is:**

> The error says -> Method Not Allowed. This url can only handle the
>   following request methods: POST.

**When i look at my Code:**

```
public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
```

ITS POST?!

When i change to GET it works without error, but also without Delete Confirmation Prompt....

**I have to Questions:**

- Why i get a Message -> allows only post, when it is Post?
- How do i get an Delete Confirmation, when i change to GET

Sorry for my English and Thank you so much for help.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the local and the remote host are the same? No special web server configuration at the remote host? Can you show us the code that calls the delete URL?

Comment: check fpr both config  (loacalhost and server) files ..  could you have not the same  values .. and let me know

Comment: Are there any JavaScript errors?

Comment: post your view page here.

Comment: I am getting the same error and it's working fine on my localhost and in fact on the  my test server but when I uploaded to my client server I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a `VerbFilter` set up in your controller `behaviors` method which is preventing to call the `delete` action to be called with `GET` method.

Something similar:

```php
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => \yii\filters\VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'index'  => ['GET'],
                'view'   => ['GET'],
                'create' => ['GET', 'POST'],
                'update' => ['GET', 'PUT', 'POST'],
                'delete' => ['POST', 'DELETE'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

You can read more about `VerFilter` [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-filters-verbfilter)

You have to options:

1. Delete the VerbFilter from the `behaviors` method
2. You can add the `data-method="post"` property to your link which and this will fire a `POST` request instead of a `GET`.